# Simple HTML DOM, how to echo only the text from anchor text

Tags: php

summary of my code:

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
```

..
I use for inner text this:

```
$element->innertext
```

It is any chance to echo only the text from anchor text unsing Simple HTML DOM, i try to crawl about 10k links but in some cases it prints **IF** is inside `<a tag` ,divs code, images code, etc.

if the `<a tag` is standard(simple) like:

```
<a href="http://www.test.com">Anchor Text</a>
```

so in this case $element->innertext will be "Anchor Text"

**BUT**

if the cases is like this:

```
1    <a href="http://www.test.com"><div id=whatever>Anchor Text</div></a>
```

or

```
2    <a href="http://www.test.com"><img src="whatever" /></a>
```

my `$element->innertext` will be:

```
Result1 <div id=whatever>Anchor Text</div>
Result2 <img src="whatever" />
```

Is there any change to print ONLY the text or should i write my own custom conditions for each case: div, img, etc?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `plaintext` attribute instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as simple as `strip_tags($element->innertext);`

The result will be an empty string if the anchor is an image.

Comment: yes it works, i didn't now about strip_tags function, many thanks.

Comment: strip_tags helped. Thanks @TecBrat

Answer (score 2):

Use Plaintext

```
     strip_tags($element->plaintext)
```

Comment: Is `strip_tags()` needed when using `->plaintext`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$mbHtml = mb_convert_encoding($element->innertext, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8');
$mbHtml = mb_eregi_replace('<(div|option|ul|li|table|tr|td|th|input|select|textarea|form)', ' <\\1', $mbHtml );
```